# How can I drop rows based if other another row respect some condition?

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
   A  B  C   D  match?
0  x  y  1   1  true
1  x  y  1   2  false
2  x  y  2   1  false
3  x  y  2   2  true
4  x  y  3   4  false
5  x  y  5   6  false
```

I would like to drop the unmatched rows that are already matched somewhere else.

```
   A  B  C  D  match?
1  x  y  1  1  true
3  x  y  2  2  true
4  x  y  3  4  false
5  x  y  5  6  false
```

How can I do that with Pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could sort those two columns so that their order of positioning could be made same throughout. Then, drop off all such duplicated entries present by providing `keep=False` in [`DF.drop_duplicates()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) method.

```
df[['C','D']] = np.sort(df[['C','D']].values)
df.drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

[image]

Comment: This seems do to the trick, even though, you have to be careful because "C" and "D" value can be swap (if the D is greater than C, not the case here)

Comment: Yeah, that's why I had to sort them before so that they're uniform throughout.

Answer (score 2):

you can compare the two columns with

```
df.C == df.D

0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
dtype: bool
```

Then shift the series down.

```
0      NaN
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
dtype: object
```

Each `True` value indicates the start of a new group.  We can use `cumsum` to create the groupings we need for `groupby`

```
(df.C == df.D).shift().fillna(False).cumsum()

0    0
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    2
dtype: int64
```

Then use `groupy` + `last`

```
df.groupby(df.C.eq(df.D).shift().fillna(False).cumsum()).last()

   A  B  C  D
0  x  y  1  1
1  x  y  2  2
2  x  y  3  4
```

Comment: Your solution makes assumption on the DataFrame values.

Comment: @fast_cen what assumption would that be?

Comment: I'm updating the question with a more complete dataframe. Thanks for the help though !

Comment: If two "unmatched" rows follow each others, you consider them as one group.

Comment: @fast_cen, you mean at the end?  Yes... that's true.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133653/discussion-between-fast-cen-and-pirsquared).

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to remove the rows where "C" and "D" matched, the method `.ix` will help you:

`df = df.ix[(df['C'] != df['D'])]`

Therefore, `df['C'] != df['D']` generates a list of booleans and `.ix` allows you to extract the corresponding `DataFrame` :)